# Nginx redirects different subdomain to Angular app not found page

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have a domain name like `sub.example.com` and I can serve apps using it by adding another subdomain level, like `test.sub.example.com`. It works fine and I could serve multiple apps one on `app1.sub.example.com` and another on `app2.sub.example.com`.
Now I have an angular app that I've served using nginx on `app.sub.example.com` using the following configuration:

```
server {
  server_name app.sub.example.com;
  listen 80;
  root /var/www/app;
  index index.html index.htm;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

It works fine and all, but the only problem I found is that if I hit a subdomain that isn't configured yet, like say `app-test.sub.example.com` I get redirected to my `/not-found` endpoint on the angular application i.e., `app-test.sub.example.com/not-found` and I can see the not found page.

```js
  // not found route configuration in the routes array
  { path: 'not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent, title: 'Page Not Found' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

Am I missing something on the nginx configuration for the Angular application?
Or is it something related to the routing on Angular? \

#### Edit:

Actually all requests seems to be redirected to the Angular application, I tried hitting `app-test.sub.example.com/` and it got me to the index page on the Angular application.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a default server block is created that handles all requests that are not configured. As described here [https://linuxserversetup.com/.../default-server-block](https://linuxserversetup.com/tutorial/setting-up-linux-web-server/reverse-proxy-server#default-server-block)

A placeholder `_` is then used as the `server_name`.

In this example, there is an index.htm file in `/var/www/default` which is then returned.

```
server {
  listen      80;
  listen      [::]:80;
  server_name _;

  root        /var/www/default/;
  index       index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.htm;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
}
```

Comment: I checked the sites-available and found a default configuration, that I enabled using `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` then reloading nginx. 
Now if I hit same endpoints as earlier, I still get redirected to the Angular app, but if I refresh, I get the nginx Not Found page.